# How to change a variable from a called method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

I am writing a bit of a dungeon crawler as I learn my way through c#. I am using visual studio and the application is a "Console App (.NET Framework)". My problem is that I use a method (a fighting sequence) that can be called from the Main method. However I want it to be able to change the balance variable in my Main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args )
{
int balance = 0;
battle(balance);
}

static void battle(int balance);
{
balance = balance + 30;
}
// I want the balance in the battle to change the balance in the Main.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the value by reference. To pass the value by reference, change the following line:

```
static void battle(int balance)
```

to

```
static void battle(ref int balance)
```

Then you can call the function as follows:

```
battle(ref balance);
```

Alternatively, you can just change your function to return the balance as a result, as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args )
{
int balance = 0;
balance += battle();
}

static int battle();
{
  return 30; 
}
```

I used 30 because this is all your original function does.

Comment: @Rabzy starting out as a new programmer I would recommend you stay away from using `ref`. In the 15 years of programming for my job I have needed to use it maybe only a 12ish times. Learning how to use classes to hold complex data and state (This is called [object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)) will help you out a lot more in the long run.

Comment: Hmm. I genuinely think you should have advocated first the "return the value" method. And possibly considered not advocating ref at all. Just because a newbie does something an awkward way doesn't mean you should help them work around the problem they have created for themselves by getting them further into trouble (ref). Take the opportunity to educate the OP properly and set him up for life, rather than having him think EVERY time the calling method needs a result, it has to use ref/out

Comment: I agree that the other answers are better just for the fact that `ref` is in most scenarios simply not the right call.

Comment: @CaiusJard There is actually a good article that talks about that. [Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925) It talks about if someone asks you if they should use a old shoe or a glass  bottle to pound a nail in you should not tell them which of the two to use and instead show them how to use a hammer.

Answer (score 1):

While using `ref` is one possible way to do this (see [Kibbee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836382/80274) for a example), another way that will help you scale up in the future is put all of your variables that relate to the player in to a `Player` class that can be passed in to methods.

This allows more variables to be added in the future and you don't need to modify the functions to add the extra parameter.

```
class Player
{
    int Health {get; set;}
    int Balance {get; set;}
}

static void Main(string[] args )
{
    Player player = new Player();
    player.Balance = 0;
    player.Health = 50;
    Battle(player);
}

static void Battle(Player player);
{
    player.Balance = player.Balance + 30;
    player.Health = player.Health - 5;
}
```

This also lets you expand in the future if you want your game to have more than one person in the party.

```
static void Main(string[] args )
{
    Player player1 = new Player();
    player1.Balance = 0;
    player1.Health = 50;

    Player player2 = new Player();
    player2.Balance = 500;
    player2.Health = 100;

    Battle(player1);
    CastHeal(player1, player2)
}
```

Comment: I'd probably also go so far as to correct the casing of the `battle` method etc

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks! I have been doing a lot of java lately and it uses functions that start with a lowercase letter so I did not notice.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the value from the method battle(int balance)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int balance = 0;
            balance = battle(balance);
        }

        private static int battle(int balance)
        {
            balance = balance + 30;
            return balance;
        }
    }
```

Or you can create a class-scope variable

```
class Program
    {
        private static int balance;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            battle(balance);
        }

        private static void battle(int balance)
        {
            balance = balance + 30;
        }
    }
```